# BeginInvoke is blocking WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, begininvoke

I've created a new WinForms project in Visual Studio 2017.
Then I've added a button and textbox to Form1 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjHal.png)).

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestWinForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private delegate void FormDelegate();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UseWaitCursor = true;
            button1.Enabled = false;

            BeginInvoke(new FormDelegate(delegate
            {
                using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
                {
                    web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    textBox1.Text = web.DownloadString("https://stackoverflow.com/");
                }

                UseWaitCursor = false;
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

When I click button1 window cursor isn't changing to WaitCursor, and when I hover cursor over ControlBox buttons they aren't "glowing". In short, `BeginInvoke()` blocks main thread for a moment. Why this is happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: No, it is DownLoadString() that is blocking your UI.  It runs on the UI thread.  All that BeginInvoke() does is make it run later, after your Click event handler completes.  Consider using DownloadStringAsync() instead.

Comment: `DownloadString()` is blocking you not `BeginInvoke()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the fellow users said in the comments, it's `DownloadString` that's blocking your UI, not `BeginInvoke` since it waits for the download to complete.

You should probably tackle this in another way, by using `DownloadStringAsync`:

```
private WebClient _web;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UseWaitCursor = true;
    button1.Enabled = false;

    _web = new WebClient();
    _web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    _web.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
    _web.DownloadStringAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/");
}

private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = e.Result;
    UseWaitCursor = false;
    button1.Enabled = true;
    _web.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is a much simpler solution that works well. However, learning about the async/await pattern is very rewarding.

Comment: @Larry this is not async await. This is the older Event Asyncronus Pattern (EAP). DownloadStringTaskAsync is the async/await method.

Answer (score 1):

I second Hans comment : the BeginInvoke only defer execution later.

What you need is either a BackgroundWorker or (better) using the [async/await pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UseWaitCursor = true;
    button1.Enabled = false;

    using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
    {
        web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        textBox1.Text = await web.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    }

    UseWaitCursor = false;
    button1.Enabled = true;
};
```

}

The DownloadStringTaskAsync will run on a worker process because it is awaitable. While it runs, the UI thread will continue to process the other events anyway, then continue its execution after the await statement as the DownloadStringTaskAsync finishes.

Comment: This is wrong, the DownloadStringAsync is not a Task. See @Scott Chamberlain comment

Comment: Oops... Updated.